# Rule for numbers where each digit differs from the other by $1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My question is simple: is there a rule that can tell me when a given numbers has all of its digit differ from the adjacent by $1$?

(I know about the $\mod10$ and shift trick, but I was hoping for a more "direct" formula).

Edit for more clarifications: I'm looking for an equation that could give me a direct result, without iterating through the digits of the number (maybe like a property this set of numbers share, though I fail to see one).

Comment: Can you give some examples?  Do the digit differences go either direction, or are they monotonic?

Comment: What could be more direct than inspection? It's hard to imagine any method that doesn't involve reading through the string of digits...

Comment: Examples: $12$, $21$, $23454567$, $4323454321$ et simila.
@lulu I was hoping to not iterate through the digits, that's why I was asking for a rule.

Comment: What you want is kind of unclear; at first you ask for *any* rule, then you say "but not the obvious rule". Perhaps you could clarify what types of rules you would view as acceptable.

Comment: You're right, I edited the question; hope it's clearer now.

Comment: What sort of method wouldn't require you to read through the digits?  Obviously, every digit has to be checked....there can't be a method that only looks at some of them.

Comment: @R.Gallo Why do you think that there should be a better way than checking digit by digit? Is it for a coding contest? The only thing that I can think of that would be more efficient than the mod 10 thing is to just read the number in as a string right from the start so that you can access each digit without doing any arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

If the number is $d_1 d_2 d_3 .. d_n$, it has the property you want if and only if:

$$|(d_1-d_2)(d_2-d_3)...(d_{n-1}-d_n)| =  1$$

(if you ever have two adjacent digits that are the same, then this evaluates to $0$, and if adjacent digits are all different, but not always differ by $1$, then this evaluates to a number greater than $1$)